# How to apply friction to an SKPhysicsBody

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have a physicsbody that I move using this code

```
motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()

        if let data = motionManager.deviceMotion?.gravity {

            if data.x > 0.2 || data.x < -0.2 || data.y > 0.2 || data.y < -0.2 {
                player.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVectorMake(40 * CGFloat(data.x), 40 * CGFloat(data.y)))
            }

        }
```

The problem is that when the player starts to move, if my device stays sill it keeps going on forever, it has a constant speed.

How can I setup a automatic slowdown like in our normal physic world (air friction simulation)?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431085/friction-in-spritekit)

Comment: Friction already applies to SKPhysicsBody when first created (I believe the default is .2)  your issue seems that you are constantly applying force,  even when you set it down,  the slightest vibrations may be applying force